# Indexing a column inside 4x1 cornerPoints array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

It would be nice if someone could help me out with how to index the x and y coordinate in that specific array:

EDIT: To be more precise I used the following code which gave me the following results:

```
sectionCorner = detectHarrisFeatures(imageSection);
```

Using this function my sectionCorner variable is of type:

```
4×1 cornerPoints array with properties:

Location: [4×2 single]
  Metric: [4×1 single]
   Count: 4

sectionCorner.Location
```

which has the following 4 cordinate pairs:

```
>>sectionCorner.Location
4×2 single matrix

 4.3865    4.0165
 4.3976   94.9175
95.3194   94.9566
95.3040    4.0371
```

After using:

```
>> sectionCorner(1).Location ||
>> sectionCorner(1,:).Location
```

I receive the following values

```
1×2 single row vector

 4.3865    4.0165
```

but i can't seem to index one of those columns. I tried using

```
>>sectionCorner(1,1).Location
```

but that results in an Error: "Invalid indexing operation."
So my question is, how am I able to properly index one of those two columns in the 1x2 row vector.

I hope that makes everything clear. Thanks for your time !

Comment: I have an array which was created by using the detectHarrisFeatures() function to find corners in an image. I'll edit the first post if you really need the information.

Comment: You are right there, it wasnt conerPoints. I edited everthing to be more precise with the problem I have.

Comment: What I want to happen is storing 4.3865 in one variable and 4.0165 in another.

Comment: Is this all you want? `one=sectionCorner.Location(1,1);`, `another=sectionCorner.Location(1,2);`

Comment: Yes!! That's exactly what I was in need of. Thank you very much!